# What does a Wi-Fi reset actually do?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data, troubleshooting, android-12

For spotty WI-FI connections, a recommended way to fix is to re-boot or toggle airplane mode to reset the connection.

Now, in Android 12 one has a feature to do that by clicking the icon with wrench

[image]

Pressing that icon resets the Wi-Fi (also mobile data) but one doesn't need to sign-in into previously connected network.

Is disconnecting and re-connecting is all that is achieved by this or other means (reboot, toggle airplane)? Or is something more happening like clearing cache etc and what's that? How does it fix the spotty connection issues?

I could not find any documentation around this

Comment: Dis- and reconnecting to a Wifi could be useful if there are multiple access points for the same Wifi but the Wifi does not support seamless handover (not sure wich 802.11 standard it was).

Comment: @Robert maybe but in a single access point situation?

Comment: Looks like this icon (labeled as "Fix connectivity") only appears when Airplane mode is off. I didn't find it before because I always turn on Airplane mode but also manually turn on WiFi on my Pixel 3a, Android 12.

Comment: [Related source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/network/NetworkProviderSettings.java;drc=master;l=1269?q=fix_connectivity). Don't have time now to investigate further.

Comment: @AndrewT indeed your observation is correct. Verified. That makes it more interesting to figure it out.. Whenever you or any one else can from the code :)